# What class features work does a Runechild's Essence Runes feature apply to?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer

I recently stared a game of D&D and I'm playing a sorcerer with the runechild subclass from the (third-party) *Tal'Dorei Campaign Setting* by Matt Mercer. I am trying to figure out how to use the runes. Part of the Essence Runes 1st-level feature of the subclass (*Tal'Dorei Campaign Setting*, p. 103) says:

> At the end of a turn where you spent any number of sorcery points for
>   any of your class features, an equal number of essence runes glow with
>   stored energy, becoming charged runes.

I'm not sure what examples of class features would be because I understand that to be stuff like hit dice and proficiencies.

**What sort of "class features" does the Essence Runes feature refer to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 Class Features which all Sorcerers get which allow you to spend Sorcery Points (*PHB 101*):

- **Creating Spell Slots** (as a bonus action)
- **Metamagic** (as part of casting a spell)

So as a Runechild, you have a number of Essense Runes equal to your Sorcerer class level.  There are 3 ways to convert Essense Runes into charged runes (*Tal'Dorei Campaign Setting 103*):

- As a bonus action, spend any number of sorcery points to convert that number of Essense Runes into charged runes.
- As a bonus action, if you have 0 sorcery points, you may spend your Action to convert a single Essense Rune into a charged rune.
- At the end of your turn, and sorcery points used for the 2 Class Features above will convert that number of available Essense Runes into charged runes.

The rules for Runechild then specify how charged runes affect you and how they can be used to activate Runechild features.

Consider this example:

> A 5th level Sorcerer uses their bonus action to spend 2 sorcery points and create a 1st level spell slot.  Then the Sorcerer spends 1 sorcery point to apply the Twinned Spell metamagic as they cast Chromatic Orb against 2 different enemies.
>
> The Sorcerer has 5 Essense Runes.  If 3 of these Runes were already charged, then at the end of the Sorcerer's turn, there is enough power to charge 3 Runes, but only 2 are available and they are both charged, but the 3rd is "wasted."  And now with 5 charged runes, the Sorcerer begins to glow (bright light for 5' and dim light for 5' beyond that).

You are correct that Hit Points, Proficiencies, etc. are Class Features, but so are all of the other entries for Sorcerer on the next 2 pages.

Also note, if you are not familiar, that the Runechild Sorcerous Origin is an alternative to the other Sorcerous Origins in the PHB.  You get all of the Class Features of Sorcerer up until the section detailing the first 2 options for Sorcerous Origin: Draconic and Wild Magic.

Answer (score -2):

You would probably want to look back at the PHB as well. The metamagic options, and converting sorcery points to spell slots are both class features that should trigger this feature.

Since I don't have the book I can't tell you what features to that specific subclass also use sorcery points but if there is anything under that subclass that follows the general rule of spend X sorcery points to do y. that should qualify.

Comment: I think you're answer could be improved by citing the sources and actually giving a specific answer to the question. As it is, your answer doesn't seem all that useful in answering OP's question.